# How to remove # tag from url in mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a home layout that have dynamic view with help of JS. Whenever I switch between pages, a hash tag appears in the URL since pages are inside  tag. I want to get rid of it. To be more accurate, I don't the URL to update. Best example for what I want is the home page of stack overflow where you can choose between (For developers) or (For Businesses), it take you to the targeted page with no URL update.

Here is my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">@StudentActivity.Resources.Language.JUC</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="#About">@StudentActivity.Resources.Language.About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">@StudentActivity.Resources.Language.Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">@StudentActivity.Resources.Language.Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#AvailablePrograms">@StudentActivity.Resources.Language.Available_Programs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Clubs">@StudentActivity.Resources.Language.Clubs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">@StudentActivity.Resources.Language.Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(StudentActivity.Resources.Language.Log_in, "Login", "Account")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(StudentActivity.Resources.Language.Register, "Register", "Account")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("عربي", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { language = "ar" }, null)</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
$(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function (event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 900);
    } // End if
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".slideanim").each(function () {
        var pos = $(this).offset().top;

        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos < winTop + 600) {
            $(this).addClass("slide");
        }
    });
});
```

})

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the href attribute of the anchor tag you are linking from. Give it an Id and use that as the selector instead.

Comment: Don't use the hash tag in other words.